# scope not found second time fileuploadchange, jquery-file-upload angularjs

Tags: angularjs, callback, jquery-file-upload

i am using jquery file upload with angular and it works great. I added my own callback on fileuploadchange, so when a user selects a different file, u get a callback. 
The upload form is in a overlay, that i close when the user is done. When a user wants to upload another image (that's where i use it form), the fileuploadchange reports a error

```
TypeError: data.scope is not a function 
var scope = data.scope();
```

The line it is refering to

```
add: function (e, data) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      return false;
  }
  var scope = data.scope();    <----------------------------------
  data.process(function () {
    return scope.process(data);
  }).always(
```

I don't know why it is giving this error. When i console.log the data variable, the second time it is missing .scope() but i have no clue why.

Anyone got a suggestion? Thanks in advance!

-- additional info ---

The controller is set in the ng-view

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/api/profile/picture" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}" class="avatar">
```

and in the controller i have the following options

```
$scope.options = {
    url: '/api/userprofile/' + $rootScope.User.UserId + '/avatar/',
    type: 'POST'
};
```

The directives are a exact copy of the once in github, provided by blueimp, https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js

Comment: Are you using the angular bindings for jquery.fileupload? If so, is the `add` function set in the controller of `$scope.options`? You may need to provide a bit more code than the above few lines.

Comment: i'm sorry :) The add function is from the example that's in the github repo, placed in my directive.js. The controller is attached to the form, so that's get called from there. In the controller function, i set 2 options, $scope.options = {
        url: '/api/userprofile/' + $rootScope.User.UserId + '/avatar/',
        type: 'POST'
    };

I dont know if you need any more code?